# How to display wordpress post according to category in pages

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a site.The problem is i have to display the categorized posts in their respective pages. I'm using a custom theme that I'm working on. basically I'm making a site in WordPress. Links to other helpful tutorials  on making will be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need to add in your webpage. Replace 1 with the category id you want.

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts(array('category' => 1));
?>
```

You can refer [this](http://www.dev4press.com/2010/tutorials/wordpress/tips/get-posts-for-a-category/) link for more detailed info.

Edit: More detailed info.

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

Now `$category` is you array of category. you can get the category name by
`$category[$i]->cat_name` So, you can search your category in array and get it's "id". and from first code you can get posts.

Comment: The problem is i have many pages. What i want to do is list post entitled Arts And entertainment in arts and entertainments page and post entitled life-style in life style page and so on.